# Send a Variable from one Python Script to another

Tags: python, json, variables

I have a python script that is constantly listening out for a json message from another server. When it receives a message one of the values is placed into a variable. Once this message is received I need another python script to be launched and the variable past over to it to be processed. Can anyone help me with how to do this?

I'm very new to python and would really appreciate any help you can give me, as I'm struggling to understand some of the other answers to similar questions.

Thank you!

Below is the code constantly running to receive messages:

```
class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print 'received an error %s' % message

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print 'received a message %s' % message
        obj = json.loads(message)
        detectedimsi = obj["imsi"]
        print detectedimsi
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
```

Then in your `on_message()` method, you can start the other process:

```
  def on_message(self, headers, message):
    …
    outputOfOtherProcess = subprocess.check_output([
      '/path/to/other/process',
      json.dumps(detectedimsi) ])
```

Your other process will receive the value you want to pass as `sys.argv[1]` in JSON format (so it will need to use `json.loads(sys.argv[1])`).

Other ways of passing the value are possible, but passing it as command line argument might be sufficient for your case (depends on the data's size and other things).

As abarnert pointed out, some things should be mentioned:

- This way of calling a subprocess will *block* until the subprocess is finished.  This might be a problem in case your script is supposed to be reactive again before the subprocess is finished.
- Calling the subprocess script by giving its path as executable might fail on systems which do not provide the direct calling of scripts.  In these cases you will have to call the interpreter (which can be accessed as `sys.executable`) and pass the path to the script as first parameter instead (and the remaining parameters after that).

Comment: That's going to block his `on_message` handler until the other process finishes, which is usually a very bad idea in a network app.

Comment: Also, you can't just run a Python script as a program like this. You need to run the Python interpreter, and pass the script as the first argument.

Comment: He only said that he got the value from a server, not that he was writing a server.  Running scripts:  There might be OSes on which you are right.  On Linuxes such Python scripts typically get their magic hashbang-line (`#!/usr/bin/env python` or similar) and execute permissions, then they can be executed as standalone-programs just fine.

Comment: The _shell_ will check a shebang line, but the OS usually won't, and you're not running with `shell=True`. Linux's `binfmt` module is a special case, but it depends on how it's configured; on many linux systems you _still_ can't do this (usually intentionally configured that way for security reasons). And on just about any other POSIX system, it's not possible at all.

Comment: Well, all system's I've been on yet it works just fine.  But thank you for pointing out that there might be sth to be done additionally in case that does not work out of the box.

Comment: As for the server issue: Many uses of many protocols need the client side to be async and responsive, not just the server. That's especially common for things like STOMP/0MQ, which the OP is using. And the fact that he's clearly defining an async message handler (`MyListener.on_message`) implies it even more strongly. And the fact that he describes his code as "constantly listening out" implies that it needs to be constantly listening, not blocking for long periods of time.

Comment: Alfe: If you consider "reformat your system as linux 2.6+" as "sth to be done additionally", I suppose that's accurate, but if you want to run on FreeBSD, OS X, Solaris, linux 2.4, etc., it's not. There is no `binfmt` module for any other platform.

Comment: You might be right there as well, but it still depends on the case.  To do it all concurrently makes it more complicated and maybe the other process terminates fast enough not to justify the additional complexity.

Comment: No, 'sth to be done additionally' could have easily been: use `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `subprocess.check_output()` and consider again how to collect any results (if necessary at all, OP didn't state that).  Anyway, I didn't understand why you prefer creating a thread to start the subprocess and then wait in that for the other process instead of just letting the subprocess run without waiting for it.

Comment: Anyway, the Pythonic approach I prefer is to try the simplest solution first.  Only if that does not work (in this case maybe because of the problems you pointed out) I will address the problems.  KISS, if possible.  Let the OP decide whether it is possible here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30744/discussion-between-abarnert-and-alfe)

Answer (score 1):

To run any other program, you just use the functions in the `subprocess` module. But there are three complexities.

First, you want to run another Python script, not a binary. Presumably you want to run it with the same version of Python that you're running in, even if there are multiple Pythons installed. So, you want to use `sys.executable` as the program. For example:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'otherscript.py'])
```

Second, you want to pass some data. For small amounts of printable string data that will fit on the command line, just pass them as an argument:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'otherscript.py', detectedimsi])
```

Then, in the other script, you just look at `sys.argv[1]` to receive the data.

If you're trying to pass binary data, or a large amount of text, you will want to pass it over a pipe. The simplest way to do that is to pass it via `stdin`. But I don't think that's relevant here.

Third, you're trying to do this inside an asynchronous network client or server. So, you can't just run another script and block until it's finished, unless you're absolutely sure that it's going to finish very fast. If your server framework has a way to integrate `subprocess`es into it (Twisted is the only one I've ever used that does, but there may be others), great. You can fake it if you can toss the process's stdout pipe into your framework's event loop (basically, if you don't care about Windows, and your framework has a way to add a file to the reactor). But otherwise, you will have to use a thread.

I'm assuming you don't need to get any results from the other script, or even know when it's done. If that's not true, it gets a bit more complicated.

Putting it all together:

```
def on_message(self, headers, message):
    print 'received a message %s' % message
    obj = json.loads(message)
    detectedimsi = obj["imsi"]
    print detectedimsi
    thread = threading.Thread(target=subprocess.call, 
                              args=[[sys.executable, 'otherscript.py', detectedimsi]])
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```